# Why node-fetch cannot retrieve cookies from response headers

Tags: cookies, fetch

I am using node-fetch to login a website. The site's response has cookies set which i can observe through `response.headers`. But when i try to `response.headers.get('set-cookie')`, it just shows part of the cookie array while `response.headers._headers['set-cookie']` works fine...
If `set-cookie` is forbidden in fetch API, why I still see it in response headers?

2020-05-26 updated:
Refer to the latest version:
https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/master/src/headers.js#L152

Answer (score 14):

Updating [Rachel's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41837373/7311767).

You need to use `.get()` instead of `.getAll()` now since version 2.

```
response.headers.get('set-cookie')
```

([Source](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/blob/a345c398b30d2bccf54abc9c45071dece69a7bba/CHANGELOG.md#headers-class))

Comment: Problem is, that you have to split the header yourself it it contains multiple cookies. This may cause issues since they are split via `,` and some cookies may contain `,`s in their cookies.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a late response, but I had this problem myself and came across your question. 
In the docs for web-api headers, I found that some browsers (and polyfills) support a deprecated getAll function. This fixed my problem.

`response.headers.getAll('set-cookie')`

([Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/get))

Comment: Well this is not very helpful if you are working with NodeJS. For current versions of node-fetch the `getAll` function is deprecated and won't work.

Answer (score 3):

If you need an array:

```
response.headers.raw()['set-cookie']
```